# Postgres: Query that can filter during table join

Tags: database, postgresql

I have a postgres database with duplicated entries on one of the table. I would like to show the created_by columns

Table1

```
id | number
1  | 123
2  | 124
3  | 125
4  | 126
```

Table2

```
id | number | created_on
1  | 123    | 3/29
2  | 123    | 4/3
3  | 124    | 3/31
4  | 124    | 4/1
```

On table 2 number are duplicated. I would like to form a single query to list the following:

```
id | number  | created_on
1  | 123     | 4/3
2  | 124     | 4/1
```

For duplicated entries only the latest entry will be included. How could I form that SQL query?

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (Table1.number) Table1.id, Table2.number, Table2.create_on FROM Table1
  JOIN Table2 ON Table1.number=Table2.number
ORDER BY Table2.create_on;
```

Actually I tried putting 'DISTINCT ON' and 'ORDER BY' in a single query (with JOIN) it gives me the following error:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions
```

Comment: There's no need to add tags to your title, that's what tags are for. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190 for the discussion.

Comment: I added the query above. Thanks for the help

Comment: What is the data type of the field `created_on` ?

Comment: created_on=date_trunc('day', now())

Comment: @Winston so the type of this field is `timestamp`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The columns in `DISTINCT ON()` have to be the first ones in the `ORDER BY` query, also if you want the latest created_on date you should order by `created_on DESC`

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (Table1.number) Table1.id, Table2.number, Table2.created_on 
FROM Table1
JOIN Table2 
  ON Table1.number=Table2.number
ORDER BY Table1.number,Table2.created_on DESC;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/5538a/2

Answer (score 0):

As you said in the comment: `created_on=date_trunc('day', now())`, so the data type of the field `created_on` is `timestamp`. Here is what you can do:

```
SELECT table_1.id, table_1.number, max(created_on) as created_on
  FROM table_1
  inner join table_2 using(number)
  group by table_1.id, table_1.number
```